# Email validation using regular expressions

Tags: java, netbeans

I have found out that I could validate email input using regular expressions. However, I do not know where do I place the expressions. Do i put them in my java controller methods, entity classes or JSP?

Comment: Why don't you just use the commons validator?

Comment: please refer to the following question, just to give some proportions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: @Artefacto commons validator? Is that an import or? I'm a java newbie ><

Comment: @RUi See http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/index.html You'll have to use an extra library though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create some `EmailValidatorClass` class which you can use in your project whenever you need to validate email addresses:

```
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
  * A class to provide stronger validation of email addresses.      
  *
  */
 public class EmailAddressValidator
 {
   public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String emailAddress)
   {
     // a null string is invalid
     if ( emailAddress == null )
       return false;

     // a string without a "@" is an invalid email address
     if ( emailAddress.indexOf("@") < 0 )
       return false;

     // a string without a "."  is an invalid email address
     if ( emailAddress.indexOf(".") < 0 )
       return false;

     if ( lastEmailFieldTwoCharsOrMore(emailAddress) == false )
       return false;

     try
     {
       InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress(emailAddress);
       return true;
     }
     vcatch (AddressException ae)
     {
       // log exception
            return false;
     }
   }


   /**
    * Returns true if the last email field (i.e., the country code, or something
    * like .com, .biz, .cc, etc.) is two chars or more in length, which it really
    * must be to be legal.
    */
   private static boolean lastEmailFieldTwoCharsOrMore(String emailAddress)
   {
     if (emailAddress == null) return false;
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(emailAddress,".");
     String lastToken = null;
     while ( st.hasMoreTokens() )
     {
       lastToken = st.nextToken();
     }

     if ( lastToken.length() >= 2 )
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your email is in a string, you might write something like the following to validate the email:

```
String email;
.
.  // load the email string
. 
if (email.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+[@][A-Za-z.]+$"))
{
.
.
.
}
else
    throw new EmailNotValidException();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String expression = "[A-Za-z]+@+[A-Za-z]+\\.+[A-Za-z]{2,4}+$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expression);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txtValidate.getText());
if(!m.matches())
{
JOpyionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create correct email validation solely by using regular expressions.

Here is a description on how to (almost) correctly validate email addresses.

---

Emails are validated according to [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). The following is simplified formal definition of the email syntax:

```
addr-spec = local-part "@" domain
local-part = dot-atom-text / quoted-string
dot-atom-text = atom *("." atom)
atom = 1*atext
atext = ALPHA / DIGIT / "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*" / "+" / "-" / "/" / "=" / "?" / "^" / "_" / "`" / "{" / "|" / "}" / "~"
ALPHA = ASCII characters in the range ‘a’ (ACSII code 0x61) through ‘z’ (ACSII code 0x7A) and ‘A’ (ACSII code 0x41) through ‘Z’ (ACSII code 0x5A)
DIGIT = ASCII characters in the range ‘0’ (ACSII code 0x30) through ‘9’ (ACSII code 0x39)
specials = "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "[" / "]" / ":" / ";" / "@" / "\" / "," / "."
quoted-string = “ *(qcontent) “
qcontent = qtext / quoted-pair
qtext = 0x21 / 0x23-0x5B / 0x5D-0x7E; All ASCII printable characters instead of “ and \
quoted-pair = \ (VCHAR / WSP)
VCHAR = 0x21-0x7E; All ASCII printable characters
WSP = 0x20 / 0x09; ASCII Space or tab characters
```

In addition to these rules the **quoted-pair** can be placed anywhere inside the **local-part**.
Note that the specials group of characters is not used. These characters cannot present neither in the **local-part** nor in the **domain part** of the email.
The **local-part** can be up to 64 characters in length and the **domain part** may be up to 255 characters (if it should be a valid DNS domain name) as long as the combined length of the whole email is less than 256 characters.

Domain names are validated according to [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) and [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt). The following is formal definition of the domain name syntax:

```
domain = subdomain / " " 
subdomain = label / subdomain "." label
label = let-dig *(*(ldh-str) let-dig)
ldh-str = let-dig-hyp / let-dig-hyp ldh-str
let-dig-hyp = let-dig / "-"
let-dig = ALPHA / DIGIT
```

Additionally [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) limits the **domain** to 255 ASCII symbols and the **label** to 63 ASCII symbols.

The *Apache commons validation* library (mentioned in the comments of the question) is a good start. It contains both domain validation and email validation, although the last time I have checked it had a few bugs in the email validation.